# How to terminate an operation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to terminate the operation and hide the keyboard so that the user can get same result when they press calculate button multiple times. My codes are following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!
    var myArray = [Int]() // empty array of int

    func convert(a:Character) -> Int {
        if (a == "1") {
           return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }            
    }

    func power(a:Int , b:Int) -> Int {
        var result = 1
        for var i = 0; i < b; i++ {
            result *= a
        }
        return result
    }

    @IBAction func binaryNumber(sender: AnyObject) {
        var text = textField.text.toInt() // for checking whether or not user left the textfield empty
        if text != nil {            
            for  i in textField.text {
                myArray += [convert(i)]                
            }

            var exponent =  myArray.count - 1;

            //Multiplying binary number with power of 2
            for var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++ {
                var base = 2;
                myArray[i] = myArray[i] * power(base, b: exponent)
                exponent--
            }

            // add up
            var sum = 0
            for var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++ {
                sum += myArray[i]
            }

            result.text = "\(sum)"
        }
        else {
          result.text = "Please enter binary number"
        }            
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {            
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider formatting the code better, select code in Xcode, control-i anf that will re-indent it. Also lot' of blank likes make it harder to understand the code, fewer statements can be seen at once. Ther eis no need to include unchanged Apple boilerplate code in the question (or at all).

Comment: What do you mean by "terminate operation"? This binary conversion is so quick (especially if you optimize it) that I don't think a user could possibly need to cancel it. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think that he basically wants to move `var myArray = [Int]()` to the beginning of `binaryNumber` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my original answer (at the end of this question), I answered a far more complicated question of how to terminate a time-consuming calculation.

But, as Sultan pointed out, you were probably asking a far simpler question, namely how to reset the calculation, so that when you calculate it a second time, you get the same result.

The root of your problem is that you have defined `myArray` to be a property (which persists between calls to `binaryNumber`), whereas it should be a local variable inside `binaryNumber`.

For example:

```
// do not define `myArray` here:
//
// var myArray = [Int]()

@IBAction func binaryNumber(sender: AnyObject) {

    // instead, define it here:

    var myArray = [Int]()

    // now the rest of your method continues as before 

    var text = textField.text.toInt() // for checking whether or not user left the textfield empty
    if text != nil {            
        for  i in textField.text {
            myArray += [convert(i)]                
        }

        var exponent =  myArray.count - 1;

        //Multiplying binary number with power of 2
        for var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++ {
            var base = 2;
            myArray[i] = myArray[i] * power(base, b: exponent)
            exponent--
        }

        // add up
        var sum = 0
        for var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++ {
            sum += myArray[i]
        }

        result.text = "\(sum)"
    }
    else {
      result.text = "Please enter binary number"
    }            
}
```

You, alternatively, could leave `myArray` as a property, but then alter `binaryNumber` to manually reset it:

```
@IBAction func binaryNumber(sender: AnyObject) {
    myArray = [Int]()

    // the rest of your method here
}
```

Personally, I prefer the former approach (making `myArray` a local variable instead; it solves the problem and avoids unintended consequences), but either approach will address your problem.

BTW, my original answer, discussing how to cancel a long running operation, is below.

--

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you want to cancel an operation, add a boolean property that indicates whether it's canceled or not, and check for the state of that variable in the calculation loop in order to determine whether to abort the calculation.
2. For this to work, though, you really have to do that calculation in a background thread. So the background thread will do calculations and the main thread will handle the UI as well as initiate/cancel calculation operations.
3. An elegant  pattern is to wrap the calculation in an `NSOperation` subclass that has an existing `cancelled` property that you can check and determine whether you want the operation cancelled.

   So, wrap the calculation in an `NSOperation`:

   ```
   class CalculationOperation : NSOperation {

       var inputString: String
       var completionHandler: (Int)->()

       init(string: String, completion: (Int)->()) {
           inputString = string
           self.completionHandler = completion

           super.init()
       }

       func convert(character: Character) -> Int {
           if character == "1" {
               return 1
           } else {
               return 0
           }
       }

       override func main() {
           // get the array of numeric values for the characters

           let digitValues = inputString.characters.map { convert($0) }

           // convert to binary

           var sum = 0
           var exponent = digitValues.count - 1;

           for var i = 0; i < digitValues.count; i++ {
               if cancelled { return }            // check to see if the user canceled the operation, and if so, quit

               let digit = digitValues[i]
               let value = digit * 1 << exponent  // using bitwise shift is more efficient than `power`
               sum += value
               exponent--
           }

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               self.completionHandler(sum)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Then your `IBAction` can add this operation to a `NSOperationQueue` in order to perform the operation in the background, first canceling any other operations on that queue:

   ```
   lazy var queue = NSOperationQueue()

   @IBAction func binaryNumber(sender: AnyObject) {
       textField.endEditing(true)

       queue.cancelAllOperations()

       let operation = CalculationOperation(string: textField.text!) { result in
           self.resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
       }
       queue.addOperation(operation)
   }
   ```
4. By the way, the binary conversion routine in the above `NSOperation` subclass can be made even more efficient using functional programming:

   ```
   override func main() {
       let digitValues = inputString.characters.map { convert($0) }
       let binaryValue = digitValues.reduce(0) { $0 << 1 + $1 }

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           self.completionHandler(binaryValue)
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, though, that these functional methods of `map` and `reduce` don't have an "cancel" feature, but they're so efficient that I don't think you'd ever need to. Anyway, if you implemented `main` this way, you'd eliminate the need for the cancellation logic when you initiate the operation.
5. Rather than checking to see if the user entered a valid binary number, I'd make sure that they can *only* enter digits `0` and `1` in the text field to start with. Just specify the view controller as the delegate of the `UITextField`, and then implement a `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` that only accepts binary digits.

   ```
   let nonBinaryCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "01").invertedSet

   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       if string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(nonBinaryCharacterSet) != nil {
           return false
       } else {
           return true
       }
   }
   ```
6. As you'll see above, you don't need to write a `power` method. There is a built in function, `pow` that does that already. Or you can use a bitwise shift operator, `<<`, which is an efficient way to do binary exponents. E.g. 2 raised to the fourth power can be represented as `1 << 4`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. My question should have been "How to reset array?". Rob solved the problem. Thanks. BTW Rob ur original answer  is complicated.